# Send Maximized Window to Another Workspace

Tags: workspaces, window

This context menu:

[image]

is available on right click only if window is not maximized.

Is there a way to do this when window is maximized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shift Crtl Alt Arrow will move the current window to the workspace up or down

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a script that does this, because I was looking for the same functionality after my job put me on a Mac, and I wanted my home machine to have the same trick.

Gist here: https://gist.github.com/Fordi/e3aa57b91cfef7561e252c2c5b801d0f

Drop that in a file, mark it as executable, and tie it to a keyboard shortcut in your prefs.  I've got mine on Super+Shift+F.